# No matter that sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid have same column names, some common fields are not inserted

Tags: magento-1.7, database, orders

I have column in `sales_flat_order_grid` that is same name and structure like in `sales_flat_order` The column name is `customer_note`.

When I create new order from frontend, in `sales_flat_order` is everything OK (order row with customer note data is inserted),

But in `sales_flat_order_grid` only `customer_note` value is empty (so order is inserted, but field stays empty).

When I update order from backend, customer_note is being copied and shows on both tables.

Comment: Can you please read question before you mark is as duplicate. That is totally another thing, he want to create new field, I already have that field, and the way I done is his solution.

Comment: As explained in the duplicate question, the sales_flat_order_grid table is updated at every order save action. Thus, that's correct way that you should be using. Check the second answer which gives details about the observer process

Comment: His answer: if you add a column name that is already used in the `sales_flat_order` table you do not need to add anything extra, on every order-save action the columns are updated (if needed).

Comment: Creating new, or using existing field, that already have helpers, observers etc. are two different things